# not able to connect superset to druid

Tags: apache-superset, druid, pydruid

I have Druid and superset running locally, but I am not able to connect them together. 
I have sample data wikiticker in Druid. I already installed pydruid with pip3: `pip3 install pydruid` (I am not sure if I need to install this to any particular location). 
I have also installed superset using docker-compose locally using [This Link](https://superset.apache.org/docs/installation/installing-superset-using-docker-compose), However, I am not able to connect Druid with Superset. I went to Data->Databases->add database. In Connection, I gave Database name as Druid and not sure what to give in SQLALCHEMY URI*
. 
I tried these:

```
druid//admin:admin@localhost:8082/wikiticker
```

```
pydruid//admin:admin@localhost:8082/wikiticker
```

```
druid://admin:admin@localhost:8082/druid/v2/sql
```

but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Druid has no built-in authentication. The SQLALCHEMY_URI string should be `druid+https://localhost:8082/druid/v2/sql/` (or `druid+http://localhost:8082/druid/v2/sql/` if you're using HTTP).

Comment: tried both but still same issue. "An error occurred while creating databases: "Connection failed, please check your connection settings""  . I could see in one of the Superset version there was a Source table which connects to Druid Cluster which I dont see in my version.

Comment: How are you running Druid locally? Also docker?

Comment: @BetoDealmeida running locally and encountering 
ERROR: (builtins.NoneType) None
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/dbapi)

Answer (score 0):

As per [documentation](https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/druid) the connection string should look like this (third variant in the question):

`druid://<User>:<password>@<Host>:<Port-default-9088>/druid/v2/sql`

Why you cannot connect might be, because of your docker setup. In the context of your superset docker container localhost refers to that particular docker container. For example the database and the redis cache are referred to as `db` and `redis` for the connection setup within the [docker-compose.yml](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) and the environment variables set in [.env](https://github.com/apache/superset/blob/master/docker/.env).

So you could extend the docker-compose.yml to include the druid container, named `druid` as well and then connect to it like this:

```
druid://admin:admin@druid:PORTTHATYOUEXPOSED/druid/v2/sql
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance that you didn't add the Root Certificate. You can either do that or disable SSL verification. See the documentation here: https://superset.apache.org/docs/databases/druid